# Antonym of the word "fault"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Consider the meaning of the word "fault" as used in the following sentence:

> It is not your fault that the warehouse burned down.

What word could we use in the following sentence:

> It is not your _____ that you won the lottery.

The closest I can think of is:

> It is not to your credit that you won the lottery.

But this sentence doesn't have exactly the same structure, because of the "to" before "your".

---

Edit: Clarification following Jason Bassford's comments:

```
              |  You are responsible  |  You are not responsible  |
--------------|-----------------------|---------------------------|
Bad event:    |       your fault      |      not your fault       |
--------------|-----------------------|---------------------------|
Good event:   |       your _____      |      not your _____       |
--------------|-----------------------|---------------------------|
```

Comment: Did a thesaurus suggest anything?

Comment: ... 'your deserts' doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Except that you're the one who picked the winning number. So, you *did* do something that led to the result, at least indirectly. Are you objecting to the normative association with *fault* (to be judged poorly) and wanting something that is neutral or the opposite—or are you looking for something like *you weren't the **cause** of the winning number being drawn*? Before understanding what you mean by *antonym*, we need to understand your interpretation of *fault* itself. (You suggest something with *credit*, but it's still not entirely clear.)

Comment: @JasonBassford "*The* cause" is problematic because every effect has myriad causes. Did you choose the drawing machine's number or did the drawing machine choose your number? Imagine driver A turning negligently into oncoming traffic and colliding with driver B. It could be argued that driver B's decision to drive to the supermarket at that particular time was *a* cause of that accident; that doesn't mean it was driver B's fault. I think blame is usually allocated to causes in proportion to each cause's degree of deviation from reasonable/normal/expected behavior.

Comment: You could say "it's not your *doing*" although, on second thought, that also can work to replace "fault" in the first sentence.

Comment: @Museful I would normally say that both *fault* and *blame* imply responsibility. But, then, the opposite of *it's not your fault* would be *it **is** your fault*. I can't really think of a way of seeing *fault* that means something that has nothing to do with you and which wouldn't be reversed by simply reversing the verb.

Comment: @JasonBassford I used "blame" *because* it implies responsibility and fault. Of course "fault" has "something to do with you".

Comment: @Museful In that case, I don't understand how you can have a *word* that's the opposite . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford Does my edit clarify?

Comment: "Fault" implies more than responsibility or doing - it implies those things *for the worse*. It is more often necessary to chastise or excuse a person in relation to bad or mistaken conduct, than to affirm (or indeed, deny the role of) exceptionally good conduct. So I'm not sure there is a specific common word to describe the opposite of fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is not your **meed** that you won the lottery.
>
> It is not by your **merit** that you won the lottery.

Though archaic, **meed** fits because *meed* is deserved or earned reward. Something obtained through fortune rather than through deserving it is not one's *meed*.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meed):

> 1 archaic : an earned reward or wage
>
> 2 : a fitting return or recompense

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meed):

> archaic : A person's deserved share of praise, honour, etc.

If you don't like using an archaism, try **merit**, which has similar meanings:

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/merit):

> 1b : the qualities or actions that constitute the basis of one's deserts

Answer (score 2):

Consider

> It is not your merit that you won the lottery.

I agree that the proposal

> It is not to your credit that you won the lottery.

does not fit well, albeit for another reason. The phrase would fit better with a statement like

> It is not to your credit that you are playing the lottery.

The meaning here is that your actions point to an undesirable characteristic of yours, perhaps a character flaw (a gambling nature) or a poor grasp of probabilities (if you believe that you will win).

Comment: So your're saying that "not to your credit" should always be interpreted as litotes?

Comment: Thanks for the new vocabulary! Not necessarily always, but in the given example without further context, I would read it like that.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to deal with trying to express an antonym:

- find the word that fills the slot perfectly. Often enough, there is an exact antonym, which matches all the salient criteria. But also there is often a lexical gap, not an exact word to fill the slot, or a candidate doesn't match everything (like register, frequency, or important contextual implications)

  For the noun 'fault', the most important thing is you did it and it was bad. The [synonym of fault](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/fault/) that seems closest is [error](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/error), and of its antonyms, the most appropriate seem to be:

  > achievement

  or

  > success

  Putting either of these into your sentence, the better one seems to be:

  > It is not your achievement that you won the lottery.

  It is not perfect, sounds a little stilted, has some implications not found in 'fault', but I think gets most of the way there. In most circumstances, 'achievement' is not a direct antonym of 'fault', but it does seem to work OK here.
- or sometimes it's just better to rewrite the sentence to communicate the same feeling but not necessarily with the same structure. Translators/interpreters have to do this all the time, often with the excuse 'you just don't say it that way, there's no word for word parallel, you just say it this other way'.

  For this, a thesaurus is often misleading because it tries to maintain part of speech, even if a different part of speech is better. I can only suggest:

  > It is not **through any skill of your own** that you won the lottery.

  or

  > You didn't win the lottery by any particular skill.

The latter is a total rewrite, and could easily be made better, but captures the opposite of fault in that you did it, but it was good ('skill' implies it was intentional, and 'of your own' or 'You' implies it was caused by you.

Answer (score 0):

In informal language, at least in the US, I know two ways to do this:

**It's not down to you**

This means *it's not because of you*.  Example:

> It's not down to you that the warehouse was saved from destruction by fire.

**It's not down to your** (special quality)

This means *it's not because of your (such-and-so) special quality*.  Example:

> It's not down to your good looks that you won the lottery.

The only dictionary definition I found of *to be down to* that matches with the above was google's

> be attributable to (a particular factor or circumstance).
>   "he claimed his problems were down to the media"
>
> be the responsibility of (a particular person).
>   "it's down to you to make sure the boiler receives regular servicing"